# How to update/trigger wishlist counter in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I am trying to add products in wishlist using **ajax** with **phtml + Controller.**
However, the product gets **added** to wishlist but the **counter** of wishlist doesn't change.

Is there a way to **trigger** an **update** for wishlist counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your js file as

```
require([
   ....
   'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (...,customerData) {
   "use strict";
   ...
   var sections = ['wishlist'];
   customerData.invalidate(sections);
   customerData.reload(sections, true);
   ...
});
```

Modify above code according to your need and you will get what you need.

Comment: Thanks @user3313626, exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update Wishlist counter**

Paste in Your Js file (your custom theme js)

```
require([                                                           
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, customerData) {
    "use strict";
     var sections = ['wishlist'];
     customerData.reload(sections, true);
});
```

This code reload the wishlist item count in every pages...